# Sorting with hidden columns in Dynatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, dynatable

I'm using Dynatable to display ajax data in a table. The table has lots of columns, so to make it easier to understand I have buttons to only show certain columns at one time. That works find until I try to sort by a column, at which point it unhides the other columns. I've tried to replicate the problem in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMPnc/4/). The dynatable part of it is pretty straight forward, although I have to copy header classes in order for it to hide the corresponding columns when the right buttons are clicked:

```
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: jsondata
  },
  table: {
    copyHeaderClass: true
  }
});
```

As you can see with the jsfiddle, if you hide some of the columns (using the buttons) and then sort by one of the remaining columns, all of the hidden columns reappear.

Has anyone else gotten Dynatable's sort function to work while also hiding some of the columns?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no luck finding a solution to this in Dynatable, so I switched over to [Datatables](https://datatables.net/), where sorting hidden columns doesn't seem to be an issue.